# xCode Storyboard: Connecting IB Elements to a source file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I don't understand how to connect elements to a source file. I have a custom UITableViewCell and I want to drag a custom label from it to my CustomCell.h file, but when I drag it over it doesn't do anything..and in storyboards there's no files owner. Is there a short answer to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the assistant editor (from the toolbar) in xcode (it'll open two views side by side, one view with the xib and the other with the corresponding .h file). control drag from your label to the created property.

Comment: that's how i usually do it...but it just keeps pulling up the containing view controller instead of the class file. I ended up being able to drag from the element to its parent view (which is the CustomCell instance in IB)..hopefully that achieves the same goal.

Comment: if that ever happens again, try opening your .h file manually by clicking on the arrow just above your file and select "Manual" which'll allow you to select your .h file from the list of files in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yeh that is pretty weird the way they've done this. As you may know in interface builder you usually drag from files owner TO the element when you want to link to an outlet. It is the same case in this example. So after you've set the class of the cell, in which you have the label. And you've created an IBOutlet UILabel in your CustomCell.h, simply control drag FROM the cell in which you have the label, and you will see your desired option to link it.

Comment: i tried that but it didn't work :( In my case I'm trying to shove in a progress view so I have @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *progressView; in my .h file and I synthesize it, and set the class for my tableview prototype cell to CustomCell.but I can't drag it. Nothing pops up.